# ¿Cómo pausar una etiqueta video si un audio esta reproduciéndose y viceversa?

Tags: javascript, html5, video

He intentado esto pero no funciona¿Qué debo hacer?

```
$("video").click(
    function(){
        var audio=document.getElementsByTagName(audio)
        $("audio").each(function () { this.pause() });
});
```

Comment: Hola Brenda, deberías crear un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema. Tal y como está puesto, ese código (aunque contiene cosas innecesarias) debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con otro evento: Un click puede significar iniciar un vídeo o pararlo, no es exactamente lo que yo usaría. Sencillamente si un vídeo empieza a reproducirse, sea del modo que sea, para los audios:

```
$('video').on('play', function () {
  $('audio').each(function() { this.pause();});
});
```