# ¿Como hacer que un audio se detenga al iniciar otro en html5?

Tags: javascript, html5, web, audio

Buenas en una página con [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) tengo un audio que se reproduce en cuanto se entra. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el audio que se esta reproduciendo se cancele al reproducir otro, que está en la página? ¿Y que este audio mismo no se reinicie al pasar a otra pagina del mismo sitio, por ejemplo de "inicio" a "información" u otras?. Gracias.

```
<div id="audioloop">
        <audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
            <source src="multimedia/musica/home.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        </audio>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

este es el código del audio que inicia en cuanto se abre la pagina.

Comment: No pongo duplicada porque es otro tag, pero muy relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109282/c%C3%B3mo-pausar-una-etiqueta-video-si-un-audio-esta-reproduci%C3%A9ndose-y-viceversa/109286#109286

Comment: cada src que pongas detendra el anterior y comenzará el ultimo si esta como autoplay, ano ser que con javascript crees audios al vuelo para cada src y quieras hacer una polifonia

Answer (score 1):

Existe un evento que permite detectar cuando se reproduce un video/audio. Por simplicidad te pongo un ejemplo con jQuery de cómo parar el resto de videos:

```
$('audio').on('play', function () { //cuando un audio empieza a reproducirse
  var current=this;
  $('audio').each(function() { 
    if (this!== current) { //todos los demás
      this.pause();  //los pausamos
    }
   });
});
```

Hacer que el audio no se pare al cargar otra página es imposible, puesto que es parte de la página que estás abandonando. Lo máximo que puedes hacer es detectar cuando el usuario deja la página, guardar el tiempo de reproducción (atributo `currentTime`) en el localStorage e intentar reproducir a partir de ese momento en la página nueva, que deberá cargar el mismo recurso. Pero de todos modos habrá una pausa entre ambos eventos.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que pasarle el `id` del `audio` que quieres pausar y listo amigo

```
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
audio.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
audio.pause(); 
}
```